# OnsenUI custom logo in nav header

Tags: css, onsen-ui

Onsen-UI question:

How can I display my logo in the top left (in the navigation section) in onsen-ui?
Is there some attribute where I can tell I want to display a logo here, something like this:

[image]

And on a sub-page, I'd like to have the logo next to the navigate back

< [logo]

[image]

Instead of "Recent" I would like to display the example image (just displayed above to illustrate that Recent are replaced by the logo)

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out, atleast for the start page of the navigator, it will suffice for now.

Set the left-button-icon to a custom class

```
<ons-navigator 
    title="Recent Ideas"
    right-button-icon="fa fa-lg fa-search" 
    left-button-icon="fa fa-lg app-logo"
    on-right-button-click="ons.navigator.pushPage('page3.html', { title: 'Page 3' })"
    page="feed.html">   
</ons-navigator>
```

define the custom class in css, using the logo image as bg.

```
.app-logo {
   background: url('../images/logo.png');
   width: 3em;
   height: 3em;
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   background-position: center .5em;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Update your OnsenUI to the last version (today is 1.1.1)
There is a new 'ons-toolbar' element and you can configure left, center, right divs.
Maybe you should do some css adaptation.